# DELPHI move 2nd line to 1st Line Memo

Tags: loops, delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, tmemo

I need to transfer the 1st line of Memo1 to Memo2, and move the remaining lines of Memo1 up.

These are the expected results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont get why this question is downvoted so much. It may be trivial but it is well asked. Although, it could have been easily answered by OP himself by reading a bit more of `TMemo` and `TStrings` documentation.

Comment: beginner Delphi Programmer here.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines[0]);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
```

Comment: sir Remy, 

does Memo1.Lines[1] will automatically go to first line?
in my example the items in memo1 should goes up when I transfer a single row from memo1 to memo2.

Comment: Yes, the remaining lines will move up when you delete a line. You could have just tried it and seen what happens.

Comment: sir Remy, 

does Memo1.Lines[1] will automatically go to first line? in my example the items in memo1 should goes up when I transfer a single row from memo1 to memo2. how will I do that? Btw Thanks Sir Remy.

Comment: You already asked that and I already answered (**yes**, the lines will move up) There was no need to ask it again. Did you even **TRY** the code I gave you yet?

Comment: Thank you so much sir Remy, this will solved my problem, I am already stuck by 2 days by this. Thank you so much.